# SpriteKit: Dynamically adding and removing jointed bodies

Tags: ios, cocoa, sprite-kit

I've built a platformer (prototype) using SpriteKit and I have a question which I haven't seen answered anywhere, including official documentation.

Since I'm starting to get impaired frame rates, I decided to remove nodes and re-add them dynamically to my scene based on their distance (essentially if they are offscreen or on) from the player's location. This seems to work fine and I can get 60fps. But this doesn't work the case of bodies that are jointed (such as a rope bridge).

I'm seeing exceptions during removal. I've finally managed to fix this by walking each node.physicsBody's joints and removing those before removing the node itself. In restoring them, I originally though that nesting each bridge under a single SKNode was the answer but this doesn't help with the joints that are added to the SKPhysicsWorld. I've played with using mutable arrays to hold onto everything but haven't figured out how remove or reattach all the nodes as they are essentially a chain. My last thought it to try to subclass the joints so that I can mark which bridge they belong to and rebuild the entire bridge in one pass as any portion of it gets close to being onscreen.

There must be an easier way to remove and rehydrate nodes (with joints). I'm probably missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: Any thoughts on this guys/gals?